# calculating fourier coefficients for piecewise function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Take the piecewise function:

F(x) = 1, x < L/2  and 2, x > L/2

Now a fourier series is defined over a full period of -L < x < L

Just using the fourier sine coefficiencts as an example, they are usually calculated as: (1/L) Int(-L,L) f(x) sin[(n pi x)/L]

But over th full period i have my function f(x) equaling two values, do i use the sum of the values?

I.e:  (1/L) Int(-L,L/2) (1)sin[(n pi x)/L] +(1/L) Int(L/2, L) (2)sin[(n pi x)/L]

Comment: Yes, you already know what to do. All that's left is to do it.

Comment: For some reason i am having a falshback that my professor said that, that is not what needs to be done. Maybe that is why i fell odd about it

Comment: If your problem is to find the Fourier coefficients, then "what needs to be done" is to find the Fourier coefficients, and if the coefficients are calculated as that integral, and you know that integral can be split up into that sum, and each summand can be evaluated explicitly, well, then you've solved the problem.